# How to query with nested object in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to Amazon DynamoDB and I want to get records according to creator id which is in parts object. so how could i fetch data from db according to creator id.

{​​​​​
"id": "123",
"parts": {​​​​​
"name": "xyz",
"createdBy": "1",
}​​​​​
}​​​​​

so how could i query and get data where parts.createdBy id is 1. and i am using AWS.document.client.

Answer (score 1):

it works a little bit different in DynamoDB, you need to create an index to be able to Query data in DynamoDB, you can't query data using the nested value `parts.createdBy`,

when you write your data to DynamoDB, you will need to extract the ID from within the object and place it in an attribute/column and create an Index in the table using that value

have a look on this article, Alex is an expert on DynamoDB and I'm confident that after you read it, you will be able to achieve what you are looking for:

https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/